# How to upload files to subfolders in mega storage platform using python library mega.py 1.0.8?

Tags: python, file-upload, upload

I would like to upload a set of files with each file to a different destination folder in mega.nz using python. I am trying to do so with the library mega.py 1.0.8 (https://pypi.org/project/mega.py/) developed by https://odwyer.software. Thank you guys for this great tool!.

Looking at the examples provided at the library site, I was able to upload a file to root directory in MEGA and also to a folder in the root (path “folderA”) with the following commands:

```
from mega import Mega

mega = Mega()

m = mega.login(“userX", "Mypasswd" )
```

#Upload to root in mega

```
file = m.upload('/home/userX/test/meganz/A.pdf')
m.get_upload_link(file)
```

#add to a specific folder in root

```
folder_destination = m.find('folderA')
m.upload('/home/userX/test/meganz/A.pdf', folder_destination[0])
```

**But** when I try to specify a different path with sub-folders, for example “folderA/folderB/randomname”. In mega, the path looks like:
[Screenshot of path in mega platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBOpa.png) and I get an error:[error message in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfOko.png)
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
The code when I get the error is (I just changed the path):

```
folder_destination2 = m.find('folderA/folderB/randomname')
m.upload('/home/userX/test/meganz/A.pdf', folder_destination2[0])
```

I change the path to other subfolders  but I get the same error. What could be the problem? I don’t see what I am missing. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the last subfolder, the place where the file will be uploaded

```
folder = m.find('randomname')
```

and upload

```
m.upload('file_to_upload.pdf', folder[0])
```

I have tried and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
folder_destination = m.find('folderA')
folder_destination2 = folder_destination.find('folderB')
```

Comment: Hi Sergio,  I tried and with second level folder (folder B in this case it works) but when I put the third level folder name (randomname) it returns null....

Comment: Mmm, I don't know. Maybe the library has some depth limitation? It's a node object, so you could also try subscript it... sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the find_path_descriptor:

```
folder_Id = m.find_path_descriptor('folderA/folderB/randomname')

m.upload('file_to_upload.pdf', folder_Id)
```